# jQuery validate plugin not validating my fancy select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In my form fancy select boxes are used. Which resulting in creating some spans and displaying it and making the actual select box with `style = "display:none"`

While googling about this I've found that jQuery validate plugin does not validates hidden fields or which are not visible on the form. But in my case how can i make use of jQuery validate to validate those fancy select box? How should I apply that exception.

Please note that I'm also aware of the `ignore` option. This part is actually helping me a lot for the hidden fields and which are not visible on the form right now.

I only want to add some exception for those select boxes which are actually visible for the user but made hidden by those fancy styling.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest thing would be to override the `display: none;` declaration.

try:

```
.hidden {
    display: block !important; /* !important to override inline style */
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: -20;
}
```

Where `.hidden` is the element you want to show (alternatively you can add this class to the element with javascript)

Comment: that part is done by the fancy box javascript. But even if I do this it will ignore the select box as its not visible on the form.

Comment: which validate plugin are you using? If the input is set to `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none;` it should still be checked